# Какой должна быть репутация, чтобы задавать вопросы чаще 1 раза в 40 минут?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, вопросы, привилегии

Как задавать вопросы чаще 1 раза в 40 минут? Какой должна быть репутация?

10 баллов - как описано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)?

или
125 баллов - как упоминают [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) ?

Comment: @AK, здесь речь о небольшом несоответствии в справке и на мете

Comment: А вы экспериментально проверьте, да и ответьте тут на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Количественные переменные задаются для каждого сайта отдельно в настройках. Обычно, они зависят от стадии развития сообщества: чем больше и активнее сообщество, тем выше порог репутации для совершения действия.

На сколько я могу знать, на нашем сайте действительны значения указанные в его справке, так как большая часть значений берется из настроек (то есть обновляется автоматически с обновлением самих настроек). Ответ – 10  баллов.

Цифры на [странице со списком привилегий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) всегда актуальны для конкретного сайта, так как отображают то, что на данный момент находятся в настройках сайта.

Comment: [Судя по всему](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4860/176217), всё-таки 125.

Comment: @alexolut Очень странно, так как страница привилегий отражает то, что находится в настройках сайта.

Comment: Вероятно, это [проблема всего SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290919/339911).

Answer (score 2):

На основании недавнего вопроса [Дефект с временем создания сообщений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4860/176217) я могу сделать предположение, что ограничение не пропадает при достижении репутации в 10 баллов. Иначе вопрос от автора с репутацией 52 балла не возник бы.

> [image: скрин]

Таким образом, скорее всего, интересующий Вас порог равняется 125 баллам.

Comment: Мама. я в телевизоре! =)

Comment: Может быть он просто не залогинился, добавляя тот вопрос.

Comment: @vp_arth это сложно было бы не заметить, т.к. появляется соответствующая форма, требующая ввести хотя бы Email.

Comment: @vp_arth, расскажите, как вы добились такого успеха у StackOverflow'еров? Какой путь вы прошли, прежде чем стали звездой? :)

Comment: Когда у меня была маленькая репутация, то тоже такое бывало. Потом пропало