# Дефект со временем создания сообщений

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

Зашёл я вчера на сайт. Хотел задать вопрос, а оно мне написало:

> Вы можете публиковать сообщения с интервалом не менее 40 минут.

Хотя я задавал вопрос два дня назад. Самое интересное, что когда я писал этот вопрос, оно опять у меня выскочило.

Из-за чего такое бывает?

Comment: Тоже замечал. Хотел ответ дать, а балалайка

Comment: Ограничения могут быть связаны с тем, что кто-то другой задает вопросы с этого же IP. Где-то был пост уже об этом.

Comment: @alexolut, а можно как-то исправить?

Comment: Набрать достаточную репутацию с помощью полезных ответов. Связанный [вопрос на MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287867/339911).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, с Вашего IP кто-то другой с недостаточной для частого создания вопросов репутацией также задаёт вопросы. И для защиты от спама (в частности) система не делает различий между Вами и кем-то ещё с тем же IP.

На Meta StackExchange есть похожий вопрос: [Bypassing the rate limiting from multiple users at the same IP address](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287867/339911)

Вероятно, какие-то изменения могут произойти в первой половине этого (2017) года:

> This is in line with some improvements we're looking at for the spam system. I don't yet have an ETA, but if I had to guess it would be the first half of next year.

Лучшее решение, которое можно предложить сейчас - набрать достаточный уровень репутации (судя по всему, 125), тогда подобных ограничений возникать не будет.

Comment: 125? Вообще-то у него 153.

Comment: @Qwertiy есть такие переменные, которые не совсем [константы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/238706/vandreew?tab=reputation) :)

Comment: Ой.. Я посмотрел, что за последние 3 недели он заработал только десятку, а вот что вопрос сильно старше, не заметил :)

Answer (score 1):

У меня тоже появился такая проблема. Я подключил VPN потом ещё раз отправил вопрос. И проблема исчезла. Так что рекомендую использовать VPN.