# Заблокированы вопросы с моего профиля

Tags: поддержка, запрет-публикаций

Захожу на задать вопрос, и мне пишет, что с моего профиля больше ответы не принимаются - я достиг лимита по вопросам. А когда откроется? Пишет, что когда мой положительный рейтинг перевесит отрицательный прошлых вопросов.

Сколько мне репутации надо заработать? 
Должна ли репутация превышать 200 баллов, чтобы блокировка снялась? Или необходимо меньше?

Предыдущие вопросы: было 9 штук, 7 из которых по 0 баллов 1 с -3 баллами, и один был с -1 баллом но его я удалил.

Вот еще пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @alexolut, неа, не тот дубликат. Тут скорее про автобан за минусы и удаление надо. Где-то был такой вопрос. А на metaSO их куча.

Comment: @Qwertiy типа надо брать и переводить? :)

Comment: @alexolut, ну можно, если своего нет :)

Comment: Насколько мне известно, такие блокировки бессрочные и снимаются только при условии приведения своих старых вопросов в порядок.

Comment: А, то есть я таки неправ! Временные. Но увеличивающиеся по продолжительности.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какой должна быть репутация, чтобы задавать вопросы чаще 1 раза в 40 минут?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4739/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5-1-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b2-40-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82)

Comment: @Other шо, опять? alexolut тоже недавно пытался к нему придубликатить, и почти смог. Вот только этот вопрос о другом.

Comment: @D-side, удаление проблемных вопросов попадает под условие?

Comment: Хорошо, что картинку добавили. Хоть перевод поправил этот :)

Comment: @Arhad скорее наоборот, восстановление с причёсыванием. Удалённые вопросы учитываются в общей оценке системой.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дело совсем не в вашей репутации, а в качестве публикуемых сообщений (в данном случае – вопросов). Система заблокировала вас автоматически по результатам голосования других участников сообщества. Если я правильно понял, это уже третья подобная блокировка (первая была на день, вторая на три).

Причина блокировки публикации вопросов у вас: [Comprehensive question quality blocks now enabled everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291142/comprehensive-question-quality-blocks-now-enabled-everywhere)

Comment: Которая будет на 416?

Comment: @alexolut К сожалению, из логов я не могу судить, как долго продлится данная блокировка (скорее всего, до тех пор пока критерии блокировки в силе).

Comment: Ок прошло пока 2 дня. Подожду еще полтора, и отмечу ваш ответ, как правильный. :)