# Как узнать сколько времени действует блокировка?

Tags: поддержка, блокировка

Есть похожая ситуация как в вопросе [Заблокированы вопросы с моего профиля](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4956/234844)

Ограничение уже давно, и не знаю навсегда ли это?

Вопросы которые задавал постарался править, а те которые удалил уже возвращать не получается.

Comment: Блокировка перманентная и действует, пока вы не перепишете уже заданные вопросы. Особенно обратите внимание на удалённые вопросы, если таковые имеются.

Comment: Нашёл один вопрос который имел отрицательный баланс голосов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748089/Как-найти-интернет-магазины-на-angular-material-design тогда удалил его, но щас восстановил, думаю из за него блокировка была

Comment: Переписал вопрос. Надеюсь, в этой формулировке он не будет крайне обширным (т. е. по сути ни о чём).

Comment: @Arhad увидел. Большое спасибо! Так действительно лучше.

Comment: Если удалить профиль и потом заново регистрироваться. То блокировка так-же останется? Вообще такое можно делать?

Comment: Где-то было написано, что при создании новой учётной записи блокировка переносится и на неё (отслеживание идёт по ряду признаков).

Comment: @Arhad а не знаете где можно уточнить? Чтобы не терять зря свой профиль

Comment: [Отписался управляющему сообществом](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44230645#44230645). Теперь надо ждать его ответа.

Comment: @Arhad спасибо!

Comment: По тому вопросу, где я ставил минус и который выправил Архад - снял минус и написал ответ. Вообще, коллеги: если кто-то пишет, что поставил вам минус - это даёт вам повод написать этому человеку "эй, я поменял вопрос - сними минус", это же в том числе и для этого мы пишем.

Comment: Создание нового профиля для обхода блокировок - действие ведущее к новому бану: профили будут объединять (если найдут) и банить. Поэтому лучше предварительно поправить всё, что можно - а потом идти к Николасу с предложением в конкретном случае разбанить. Думаю, на первый раз пойдут навстречу, что мы - изверги что ли?

Comment: Понял, значит нужно все вопросы править

Comment: Вообщем ещё один вопрос нашёл https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626842/Что-лучше-изучать-для-больших-и-сложных-приложений-angular-или-react вообщем не зря мне заблокировали возможность спросить. Вопрос ~год назад написан :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, система «штрафует» за отрицательный рейтинг, удалённые и закрытые вопросы. У вас есть три вопроса с отрицательным рейтингом, один из которых имеет -5. Вам необходимо улучшить качество этих вопросов, а не удалять их. Скорее всего, это поможет.

Comment: Вчера правил все вопросы которые только мог, и сегодня уже могу задать вопросы. Очень рад что получилось :)

Comment: @ValeriuVodnicear это из-за темы на мете, участники увидели вашу заинтересованность и поставили несколько "+" :-)

Comment: Заметил, спасибо всем кто поддерживал! :)