# Возможно ли вылезти из бана?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация, блокировка, заблокированные-вопросы

Я уже как месяц торчу в лимите по вопросам, и не могу ничего задавать. Есть ли какая-то формула, или статья, по которой можно узнать можно ли вылезти из бана, и как???

Я пытался выбраться с помощью увеличения репутации(уже набрал около 200 после бана), но мне кажется, дело не в этом.

Может, где-то есть страница для обращения к админу и остальным с таким вопросом и 
просьбой разблокировать меня?

***P.S. Мне удалось это.  После месяца набирания репутации, а потом обращения в чат с просьбой помочь мне, я теперь могу снова задавать вопросы.***

Comment: Можно. Вот в [этом вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7807/213987) ссылка в [первом же комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7188/213987) - посмотрите и действуйте по аналогии: написать управляющему сообщества, планомерно вычистить все ответы. Публиковать формулу отказываются (в т.ч. и [на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315304/260198)), мотивируя "слишком много будет желающих обойти её". Так что - только ручной контур по запросу участника

Comment: @AK Я уже пытался, не получалось, было только хуже. Попробую ещё :)

Comment: Вероятность вылезти из question ban не очень велика, особенно если ваши удаленные заминусованные вопросы уже пропали из профиля. Только ждать 6 месяцев, пока система даст задать новый вопрос.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight я думаю, можно попросить модераторов дать список таких вопросов.

Comment: Восстановил 2 вопроса из 5 удалённых. А вообще, тебе же в прошлый раз говорили, что надо сделать...